# How to configure the timeout for the Debug Control's "Connect to target" operation?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt, ds-5

Using Eclipse CDT/DS-5 for ARM, I am debugging a hardware setup using the DSTREAM target connection.

Occasionally, the connection to the board fails. However, the failure indication takes a long time to complete, and during this time, the debugger GUI is essentially non-responsive.

How can I configure the operation's timeout?

Comment: I noticed that if I power-down the board, it helps bailing out of the connect/disconnect process.